# How to show the textview just below that cell which is clicked.?

Tags: android

[image: This is the reference image link]

I am getting the images from Flickr and showing them in gridview.
The problem is the textview is getting displayed on the top of gridview.

What I did till now:

```
      mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> gridView, View view, int pos,
                                long id) {

            GalleryItem item = mItems.get(pos);
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            layout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            TextView textview = new TextView(getContext());
            textview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textview.setText("Get the Position " + pos);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            layout.addView(textview);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Here's what I want. Here's what I did. Good. Now, what's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: As you can see in the image a text view is getting displayed when any cell in grid view is clicked.I am just thinking of implementing that kind of UI.I tried adding a text view dynamically but it is getting displayed on the top of the grid view.@LuizFernandoSalvaterra

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recycler view with GridLayout Manager and add textView below imageView in custom layout and show/hide depending on View clicked.

Find the below reference:
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I obtained the view by using a  custom listview.With two images and a text view in it.@Aditi

Comment: Could you post your tupple layout so i can view the alignment of images and textview

Comment: I have two image views in Linear layout orientation horizontal and generating text view dynamically, below the linear layout.@Aditi